# How do I set the size of the list, so that when swiped to the left, it doesn't exceed the Card layout limit in Slidable Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm using slidable flutter, but i'm having ui problem. How do I set the size of the list, so that when swiped to the left, it doesn't exceed the Card layout limit.
this is the problem image:
[image]

this is my code:

```
ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        itemCount: member.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: Slidable(
              key: const ValueKey(0),
              endActionPane: const ActionPane(
                extentRatio: 0.2,
                motion: ScrollMotion(),
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: null,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEEB4B0),
                    foregroundColor: Color(0xffCB3A31),
                    icon: Icons.delete,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(),
                  title: Text(member[index]["name"]),
                  subtitle: Text(member[index]["noHp"]),
                  onTap: () {}),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in sizedbox for making that into the size you want.

In your Case -

```
ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    itemCount: member.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Card(
        child: SizedBox(
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20, 
Slidable(
          key: const ValueKey(0),
          endActionPane: const ActionPane(
            extentRatio: 0.2,
            motion: ScrollMotion(),
            children: [
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: null,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEEB4B0),
                foregroundColor: Color(0xffCB3A31),
                icon: Icons.delete,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(),
              title: Text(member[index]["name"]),
              subtitle: Text(member[index]["noHp"]),
              onTap: () {}),
        ),),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: thanks, but I've tried and it doesn't work